# Reapplying for same credit card after collections

Tags: credit-card, debt-collection

My Amazon's Chase credit card bill was sent to collections in March 2019 due to some financial issues I had. I paid off the debt completely in collections and my credit rebounded. My credit card account was deactivated. I would like to apply for the same card again (because this is Amazon's Chase credit card which provides 5% cash back on Amazon purchases). Do you know if it is possible to get the same card again after it was closed and sent to collections? Or will Chase/Amazon not allow me to? Are there any rules against re-applying? E.g. Is there a cool-off period?

I assume that each credit card company has their own internal/private rules about this, but I'm curious if anybody has had a positive experience with reapplying for the same card.

Comment: Try applying.  The worst they can do is say no, and maybe register a "hard pull" on your credit score.  What's your score right now?

Comment: @RonJohn I am not sure if it is the wisest thing to apply. Assume they have a "cool-off period" (as the OP calls it) of 24 months, and a rejected application adds 12 months to this period. (Numbers are completely made up.) So it might be wise to at least wait a month or two. And it is wise as well to ask here because maybe someone made already a similar experience.

Comment: Let us know how it went. I'll be waiting!

Comment: thanks for the encouragement everybody. I'm waiting a few months to minimize hard pull issues but I'll update after I try, thanks!

Comment: You might consider the store card (https://www.amazon.com/gp/cobrandcard/marketing.html) as an alternative. Same 5% back benefit, different bank (Synchrony). Or, if you have any business spend, Amex has one as well. https://www.americanexpress.com/us/credit-cards/business/business-credit-cards/amazon-business-prime-card/.

Comment: hi everybody, i tried after a couple of months and was denied. But there was no soft/hard pull on my credit which suggests that it might be an internal flag that prevented the application from going through.